# How to delete a single file if older than x days?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I need to delete a single file before starting a program, but this should be done only when it's older than a day.

At the moment I execute always in a command prompt window:

```
del /f filepath
*run program*
```

I know, there is this option to do it for multiple files via batch:

```
ForFiles /p "path" /d -X /c "cmd /c del @file"
```

But I want to do this only for a specific file, **do I have to use forfiles or is there another little bit faster option without iteration?**

Comment: Open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/), run `forfiles /?` and read the output help. Use option `/M` with the file name to match just the file you want to delete if older than X days. For example: `forfiles /P "path" /M "file name" /D -1 /C "%ComSpec% /C del /A /F @file"`. The __FORFILES__ option `/S` does not make sense in this case and should not be used here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code:

```
forfiles /p "path" /m "file name" /d -Number of the days older mean the value of your X days /c "cmd /c del /f /q /a @file"
```

You got the code in your question hard coded. The `/s` switch of `forfiles` iterates through all the sub folders of given path. So there is no use of that switch. And the value of `/d` switch deletes files more older than 30 days, but you have wanted anonymous X days. Change them and your code will work. For more help, start cmd and type `forfiles /?`.